Defining datasources in wildfly31 standalone.xml file using credential-reference to refer passwords
Is there something changed between wildfly-26 and wildfly-31. I was able to define a data source , while providing the username and password inside  tag for the data source  tag throws me an error saying it's not a valid tag. looks like it was deprecated or unsupported for wildfly31
Following was the approach that i used to define a data sources
WildFly 26
WildFly 26 data source configuration which used to work
<datasource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/bankstate_kghs" jta="true" pool-name="jdbc/bankstate_kghs" statistics-enabled="true" use-ccm="true" use-java-context="true" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:7.0">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://piligerwest1:1433;databaseName=master;trustServerCertificate=true;applicationName=bankstate</connection-url>
    <driver>bankstate</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <prefill>false</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>admin</user-name>
        <credential-reference alias="bankstate-admin" store="bankstate_cred_store"/>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLExceptionSorter"/>
        <background-validation-millis>120000</background-validation-millis>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
</datasource>

The above approach wasn't working while defining a data source for WildFly 31 because it doesn't support  and  tag
WildFly 31
I tried below approach for wildfly31 by following the wildly documentation and domain.xml file but this doesn't works.
<datasource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/bankstate_gts" jta="true" pool-name="jdbc/bankstate_gts" statistics-enabled="true" use-ccm="true" use-java-context="true" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:7.1">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://piligerwest1:1433;databaseName=master;applicationName=bankstate</connection-url>
    <driver>bankstate10</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <prefill>false</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security username="admin" password="Ajndnjenekdek">
    
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLExceptionSorter"/>
        <background-validation-millis>120000</background-validation-millis>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
</datasource>

How can i define username and password using credential-reference  inside  in wildfly31. The reason we are using credential-reference  because of security issues and we want the user password to be hidden.

You haven't described the error you're getting, but I think I see the issue.
In WildFly 26 you have the following in your snippet:
<security>
    <user-name>admin</user-name>
    <credential-reference alias="bankstate-admin" store="bankstate_cred_store"/>
</security>

In WildFly 31 you changed it to:
<security username="admin" password="Ajndnjenekdek">
    
</security>

Note you switched from using elements to attributes.
I'm not really sure where you got the reference to a domain.xml. As you're question is about the standalone.xml configuration.
In either case it's really best to use a management interface to modify the configuration. This could be the web console or CLI as an example.
CLI Example
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=jdbc\/bankstate_kghs:add(connection-url="jdbc:sqlserver://piligerwest1:1433;databaseName=master;trustServerCertificate=true;applicationName=bankstate", \
    driver-name="bankstate", \
    jndi-name="java:/jdbc/bankstate_kghs", \
    use-ccm=true, \
    jta=true, \
    statistics-enabled=true, \
    use-java-context=true, \
    enabled=true, \
    min-pool-size=0, \
    max-pool-size=100, \
    pool-use-strict-min=false, \
    pool-prefill=false, \
    user-name=admin, \
    credential-reference={alias=bankstate-admin, \
    store=bankstate_cred_store}, \
    valid-connection-checker-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker, \
    exception-sorter-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker, \
    background-validation-millis=1200, \
    background-validation=true, \
    idle-timeout-minutes=1 \
)


In wildfly 31 the entry should be as below:
    <security user-name="admin">
        <credential-reference store="bankstate_cred_store" alias="bankstate-admin"/>
    </security>

This can also be done via CLI:
batch
/subsystem=datasources/data-source="jdbc/bankstate_gts":write-attribute(name=credential-reference,value={store="bankstate_cred_store", alias="bankstate-admin"})
/subsystem=datasources/data-source="jdbc/bankstate_gts":undefine-attribute(name=password)
run-batch

